# Pass flow type to react component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, generics, flowtype, definition

I have a component that uses another component from an external project. How I can generate flow type in the external component without duplicate types?

For example:

```
import {ExternalComponent} from '@npm-component/another-component';

type CurrentComponentType = {|
  data: {
    count: number,
    items: [{code: string, descroption: string}]
  }
|};

export CurrentComponent = ({data}: CurrentComponentType) => {
const onClick = () => {}
return <ExternalComponent data={data} onClick={onClick}/>;
}
```

Currently, I duplicate flow type in the external component

```
type ExternalComponentType = {|
  data: {
    count: number,
    items: [{code: string, descroption: string}]
  }
|};

export ExternalComponent = ({data}: ExternalComponent) => {
const onClick = () => {}
return data.items.map(({code}) => <span>{code}</span>);
}
```

For example what I want

```
type ExternalComponentType = GenerateTypeHere;

export ExternalComponent = ({data}: ExternalComponent) => {
const onClick = () => {}
return data.items.map(({code}) => <span>{code}</span>);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends if the library you're importing from actually has flow types exported. Let's assume it does for the sake of answering the question.

If they do, their code would look something like this

```
// @flow
export type ComponentProps = {};

export default Component = () => ...
```

Then in your code you can import it like so

```
// @flow
import Component, { type ComponentProps } from '@npm-component/another-component';
// Or if you want to import just the type on a line
import type { ComponentProps } from '@npm-component/another-component';

type CurrentComponentType = {
  ...ComponentProps,
  a: string, // If you want to extend the props with more functionality
};

export const CurrentComponent = ({ data }: CurrentComponentType) => {
  const onClick = () => {}
  return <ExternalComponent data={data} onClick={onClick}/>;
}
```